# http service 503 unavailable Only for HTTPS

Tags: iis, asp.net, azure

My azure website is working fine with http. Now, I have added a self-signed certificate and a binding in IIS 7. When I run the application with https, I get certificate error warning. When I confirm 'run anyway'. Then I get 'http service 503 unavailable' continuously only with https. My binding is correct(because I am seeing certificate error first time). No log found in IIS log files. Tried, IIS Failed-request tracing, no log found. I have confirm that iis user can register both port 80 and 443(using netsh). Any idea?

**Edit**: The site is now working if I use specific IP in binding. But when I chnage this to 'All Unassigned' I got the same error? why?

Comment: Do you have another site in IIS?

Comment: @ShaneMadden, I have also checked with just one 1 running site

Comment: In my case it does not work even if IP is indicated. Exhausted and run out of idea: no info about the reason of error.

Comment: For IIS 7.x, the key is to analyze Windows HTTP API settings and learn whether certificate mappings are proper, so that incoming HTTPS requests arrive on the right site. 503 is not surprising but the actual cause requires access to the server itself for further analysis (likely to be another application hooks to port 443 via reserved URLs), https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#ip-based-bindings

Answer (score -1):

I've seen that before and the short answer is that you can only bind an SSL to a single IP and port that cannot be shared.

Comment: Binding a certificate to "All unassigned" is supported, so "can only" is incorrect.